# In proportional mode how do I pull together 2 vertices that are facing each other?

Tags: vertices

I want to create a blood cell model. So first I create a UV Sphere, then I select the top vertex and the bottom vertex of the sphere, and now I want to pull the 2 vertices closer together in proportional mode. 
How can I do that?

Comment: "2 vertices that are facing each other" could you add some screenshots of how could vertices face each other? Also some references pictures of your desired result and what you have problem with

Comment: @MrZak "now I want to pull the 2 vertices closer together in proportional mode. How can I do that?" This is what he wants. I think it's clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select both vertices and scale along the z axis. So press [S] and then [Z].
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a sphere and enter edit mode.

Select the top and bottom verts.

With the proportional editing on (Press O key) select connected option

Press S to scale down and Z to Z axis and scroll the mouse forward and backward to change the shape.

[image]